# MS Visual C++ uninstalled, now Office '13 icons do not display properly

Tags: microsoft-office-2013

I have a user that uninstalled some (all?) of their 'Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable' programs and the OS (Win8.1 Pro x64) is somewhat broken now. All MS Office '13 programs work, but the icons looks broken - they do not display what the program is (such as Outlook), but rather just a generic icon.

Normally I would do a "repair" of MS Office, but as we all know Microsoft removed that feature from Office 2013 (EDIT: on closer inspection, maybe not?). How can I fix this? I do have other machines with working Office 2013 shortcuts, so maybe just copying them over to the broken machine (in their respective paths) would work...? **Looks like the shortcut icon graphics were somehow deleted.** Thanks.

EDIT: I copied shortcuts overs from a working PC, but on the broken PC "change icon" is just grayed out.

Comment: Why don't you just create new shortcuts from the folder where the binaries are in? Furthermore, there should be a repair option available from the "programs" control center add-in. If there isn't, just completely un- and reinstall.

Comment: Thanks, Patrick. I was mistaken on the Repair option for Office 2013, you're right. However, I tried the repair and it did not help. My predecessor purchased H&B keys for the business (don't get me started), so reinstall is tough because I don't have the license info.

Comment: I copied the contents of `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\Root\VFS\Windows\Installer\{90150000-000F-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}' (where the icons for Office '13 on a good PC live) over to the broken PC, but it did not help.

Comment: If you still have the PKC, you should be able to recover the license with the help of microsoft support.

Comment: It was purchased from "My Software Choice" so I'm not sure if it's sketchy or not. They have ok reviews but last time I tried a reinstall (from another H&B key he purchased from them) I had to phone activate.

Comment: Go the safe route. Order a new license, wipe the office install, reinstall.

Comment: Not worth it, I've told the user to just live with it. All the Office programs work fine.